# How to position error message

Tags: jquery

I'm using jquery to post a form and if there is an error, I need to show it to the user. Ideally, I would like to echo the message in a certain place on the form but all I'm able to do is have it echo at the top of the screen which is not really good because the form is long and neither the top or the bottom are readily viewable without having to scroll up or down. How can I fix this? What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the best way is to roll your own modal dialogue solution, or an overlay that you'll put the message in. There are jQuery plugins that will help with that, like [SimpleModal](http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/) or [jQuery UI Dialogue](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/) (this one's a bit heavier).